# How to show all items in ArrayList that contain duplicate values?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have a People list that contains name, age, and car.  I am able to printout the string values for one set fine.  However when I add another name, age, car to the list only the last items/list is shown.  How do I printout both sets of people data?

```
    List<People> peopleInfo = getInfo(ppl);
    String peopleResults = mapper.writeValueAsString(peopleInfo);
    for(People model : peopleInfo) {          
        People people = new People(model.getName(), model.getAge(), model.getCar());
        ToJSON peop = new ToJSON(people);

         ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
         ObjectWriter writer = mapper2.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
         writer.writeValue(new File("file.json"), peop);
```

**getInfo Method**

```
private List<People> getInfo(String ppl) {
    List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();
    People people = new People();

    //1st Person
    people.setName("Tim");
    people.setAge("22");
    people.setCar("Ford");

    //Second Person
    people.setName("Susan");
    people.setAge("42");
    people.setCar("Toyota");

    peopleList.add(people);

    return peopleList;
}
```

Comment: You're not creating two People objects. You are creation just one and you erase values when assigned in the second time.

Comment: Thanks.  What if I don't know how many people there will be.  In other words I wouldn't be setting my values but retrieving from the DB.  Is that where the ID field in DB comes in?

Comment: All depends on what you want to do with people list. You must iterate on the list coming from DB and containing people. and then do some work that you judge necessary for your functionalities. Your need is not clear to me.

Comment: I would get the items from the DB and display them in JSON format.  There could be 50 people in the list with like and alike information.  So in the code above I'm returning a peopleList and writing it in JSON format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redefining people when creating the second person so only the second person is added to the list

```
//1st Person
people.setName("Tim");
people.setAge("22");
people.setCar("Ford");

//Second Person
people.setName("Susan");
people.setAge("42");
people.setCar("Toyota");

peopleList.add(people);
```

A fix would be to create multiple people objects or add the people right after defining them

```
People people = new People();
People people2 = new People();

People.setName("Time");
People2.setName("Susan");

peopleList.add(people);
peopleList.add(people2);
```

Or the latter

```
people.setName("Tim");
people.setAge("22");
people.setCar("Ford");

peopleList.add(people);

people.setName("Susan");
people.setAge("42");
people.setCar("Toyota");

peopleList.add(people);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `people` object will have the latest values in it. you need to pass new object every time as you do like this,

```
People people = new People();
```

An simple example is that you can do it like ,

```
People people = new People();

//1st Person
people.setName("Tim");
people.setAge("22");
people.setCar("Ford");

//Second Person
 People people2 = new People();

people2.setName("Susan");
people2.setAge("42");
people2.setCar("Toyota");

peopleList.add(people);
peopleList.add(people2);
```

so that your `peopleList` will hold 2 objects.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot one step really.
Let's go at it step by step:

```
List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();
```

You created your empty list

```
People people = new People();

//1st Person
people.setName("Tim");
people.setAge("22");
people.setCar("Ford");
```

You created a `People` object instance and set some values on it

```
//Second Person
people.setName("Susan");
people.setAge("42");
people.setCar("Toyota");
```

Here you don't create a new person, but overwrite the values of your first person

```
peopleList.add(people);
```

Finally you add your first person, containing the values of the second person, to your list.

You will have to create a new `People` instance for your second person, set the values on that one and add it to the list, just like with your first person.

Comment: Thanks.  What if I don't know how many people there will be.  In other words I wouldn't be setting my values but retrieving from the DB.  Is that where the ID field in DB comes in?

Comment: Usually you get some form of result set from a database. The common approach would be to loop over that result set, each iteration accessing a single person result, constructing your object instance and add it to your list. Just remember to instantiate the list outside of the loop, or you will keep overwriting that one to ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
  private List<People> getInfo(String ppl) {
        List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();
        People people = new People();

        //1st Person
        people.setName("Tim");
        people.setAge("22");
        people.setCar("Ford");

        peopleList.add(people);
        People people = new People();

        //Second Person
        people.setName("Susan");
        people.setAge("42");
        people.setCar("Toyota");

        peopleList.add(people);

        return peopleList;
```

You are not creating another person object and adding the previous object, you are just modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

You create a "People" object and set the name, age, and car . . . and then set the name, age and car of the people object again.  You need two different People objects:

```
People people1 = new People();
People people2 = new People();

//1st Person
people1.setName("Tim");
people1.setAge("22");
people1.setCar("Ford");

//Second Person
people2.setName("Susan");
people2.setAge("42");
people2.setCar("Toyota");

peopleList.add(people1);
peopleList.add(people2);
```

Also, you pass a parameter to your method `getInfo(String ppl)` but don't use it.  What is that parameter for?